# phonegap sqlite database sum query result

Tags: sqlite, cordova, sum

see the following code,

```
function queryData(tx) {
   tx.executeSql('select sum(income) from balancesheet where id=1', 
   [],
   rowsDataHandle, 
   errorCB);
}

rowsDataHandler = function(tx, results) {
var row = results.rows.item(0).income;

document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = 'Your Total income:\t'+ row;
```

};

income is an integer field.
please check the query as well. and how to get sum of all income transactions.

Comment: I am getting result undefined

Answer (score 3):

Try using an alias for the sum:

```
select sum(income) as totalincome from balancesheet where id=1
```

and then...

```
rowsDataHandler = function(tx, results) {
    var row = results.rows.item(0).totalincome;
    document.getElementById("mydata").innerHTML = 'Your Total income:\t'+ row;
}
```